# Node.js Http server, readstream end event firing console.log twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming

Code is listed below.  The problem is that the console.log() is firing twice, indicating that rs.end is firing twice, even though I only registered it to fire once.  If I comment out res.end() it only fires once, so I know the call to res.end is causing rs.end to fire as well, I just don't understand why.

I recognize that this could just be a misunderstanding of the event system or the server streaming objects, neither of which I've looked much into.

Where it gets a bit odd though, is that if I change that console.log to be res.write so that it's writing it to the browser, it only writes it to the browser once, even with res.end() being called.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {

    var rs = require('fs').createReadStream('sample.txt');

    //Set the end option to false to prevent res.end() being automatically called when rs ends.
    rs.pipe(res, { end: false });

    rs.once('end', function() {
        console.log('Read stream completed');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are seeing two separate http requests: the one you explicitly sent and the one sent automatically by the browser for `/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 1):

the browser with every response is looking for a favicon.ico , in this case  because you didn't send  a html with a `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>` send another request looking for that, if you are trying to avoid it you can do something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var rs;
    if(req.url !== "/favicon.ico") {
        rs = fs.createReadStream('sample.txt');
        //Set the end option to false to prevent res.end() being automatically called when rs ends.
        rs.pipe(res, { end: false });

        rs.once('end', function() {
            console.log('Read stream completed');
            res.end();
        });
    } 
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: What about the case when the request is for the favicon? You should still respond to that request in some fashion...